# ng-class and matching value inside array angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-class

```
ng-class="{'active' : question.chosen == key}"
```

The above sets my class as `active` when `question.chosen` matches `key`. This means that `$scope.question.chosen` only has a single value.

In the even `$scope.question.chosen` has `["a","b","c"]` how would I iterate through that with ng-class to match `key`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
ng-class="{ 'active' : question.chosen.indexOf(key) >= 0 }"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the ng-class object have keys as class names and values as functions that return booleans.

I set up a fiddle for you:

```
    <li ng-class="{'active': isActive('one')}">one</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DrDyne/gZg7q/2/

Tell me if this helps :)